# Proof with Möbius function, divisor function and little omega function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, mobius-function

For all natural numbers n, show

$\sum_{k|n}$$\mu$(k)d(k) = (-1)$^{\omega(n)}$

where

$\omega$(n) := $\sum_{p|n}$1

$\omega$(1) = 0

$\mu$(n) is the Möbius function and d(n) is the divisor function

So I know the $\omega$(.) function is the sum of all distinct primes of n, but this problem doesn't make sense to me. The RHS will always be $\pm$1 but the LHS seems like it could be other values since d(n) can be greater than 1.

Any pointers or solutions would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is $\prod_{p|n} (1+(-1)\times 2) = (-1)^{\omega(n)}.$

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions on how to transform the left hand side of the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to query by OP we observe that with $g(n)$ multiplicative
we have

$$\sum_{d|n} g(d)
= \prod_{p^v||n} (g(1)+g(p)+g(p^2)+\cdots+g(p^v)).$$

Here we have $g(n) = \mu(n) d(n)$ and with $\mu(n)$ zero when $n$
is not squarefree this becomes

$$\sum_{d|n} g(d)
= \prod_{p^v||n} (g(1)+g(p)).$$

Observe  that $g(1)  =  \mu(1)d(1) =  1$  and $g(p)  =  \mu(p) d(p)  =
(-1)\times 2$ so we get

$$\sum_{d|n} g(d)
= \prod_{p^v||n} (1+(-1)\times 2)
= \prod_{p^v||n} (-1)  = (-1)^{\omega(n)}$$

as claimed.